# HTML/CSS bootstrap alerts change position of elements already on page

Tags: html, css

I am using the bootstrap HTML/CSS and when an alert pops up, it is shifting the position of my elements already on the page. I would like those elements to stay in one place when the alert comes up. Below is the code and images of what is happening.

[image]

[image]

Login.html

```
{% extends "users/authentication_base.html" %}
{% block title %} Login Page {% endblock title%}
{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <div id="form_errors">
                {% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
                    <strong>{{ value }}</strong>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Login.css

```
.wrap-login100 {
  float: inside;
  position: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 55px 55px 37px 55px;

  background: #9152f8;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7579ff, #b224ef);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #7579ff, #b224ef);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7579ff, #b224ef);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #7579ff, #b224ef);
}
```

bootstrap.css

```
.alert {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  position: fixed;
}

.alert-dismissible .close {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.75rem;
  right: -1.25rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  color: inherit;
}
.alert-danger {
  color: #721c24;
  background-color: #f8d7da;
  border-color: #f5c6cb;
}

.alert-danger hr {
  border-top-color: #f1b0b7;
}

.alert-danger .alert-link {
  color: #491217;
}
```

Comment: It looks like they share a parent or am I wrong? If so you can add the style display: flex and justify-content: center to the parent Hope it helps!

Comment: You could change the width and/or make the alert a flex with the `d-flex` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these to your .wrap-login100

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```